# WHERE REGEXP_MATCH not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to filter data where I'm extracting from Google Analytics data sessions, clientid and a custom dimension. The custom dimension is only set in some cases and we, unfortunately do not set a default value. It can therefore be blank or null. The values all have a format which looks like this: 5lkfzls6e5xt8aazyygsop. They all start with a number. I thought my expression below would therefore only return custom dimensions which have something present, but I still get all other values returned.

```
SELECT date, 
   SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
   fullVisitorId,
max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then hits.customdimensions.value end) dogs
FROM [data_source]

   WHERE REGEXP_MATCH (hits.customdimensions.value, '^[0-9]')
GROUP BY date, fullVisitorId
ORDER BY dogs DESC
```

Edit, added sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Your regular expression should be only returning values that start with a digit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Legacy SQL - bellow is for Legacy SQL

1 - Below, which looks like exactly query in yo question does work!!!

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT DATE, 
   SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
   fullVisitorId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 3 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) dogs
FROM [project:dataset.table]
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(hits.customdimensions.value, r'^[0-9]')
GROUP BY DATE, fullVisitorId
ORDER BY dogs DESC
```

2 - As alternative  - try below version

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT DATE, 
   SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
   fullVisitorId,
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 3 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) dogs
FROM [project:dataset.table]
GROUP BY DATE, fullVisitorId
HAVING IFNULL(dogs, '') != ''
ORDER BY dogs DESC
```

3 - I just tested both and they both work  - if they do not work for you  - it means only that something with your data that you don't specify in you question

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#regexp_match), your syntax might be slightly off and you should be doing this:

```
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH (hits.customdimensions.value, r'^[0-9]')
                                                ^^^ you omitted the r
```

Comment: Good catch, but does not seem to change the result; I still get null values appearing in the data.

Comment: Wait...are you getting back _all_ values, or just matches along with _nulls_?  Your question is unclear now.

Comment: It's returning all values

Comment: Then I question your data or table design.  Please show sample data and your table definition.